# Kibana dashboard 5601 port issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

we setup kibana dashboard in linux with port 5601 . Suddently setup dsahboard is not working. WE couldn't find the solution . So we change the port no 5601 to 5602 in kibana yml file. After restarting the server, i am able to lanuch the dashboard. But we need to run 5601 port since kibana dashboard is mapped to 5601. Any idea how can solve the issue.

start up log:

```
username@x.x.x.x:folder-path > kibana
  log   [09:51:27.806] [info][status][plugin:kibana@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:27.847] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:27.850] [info][status][plugin:xpack_main@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:27.855] [info][status][plugin:searchprofiler@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:27.858] [info][status][plugin:ml@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:27.891] [info][status][plugin:tilemap@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:27.893] [info][status][plugin:watcher@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:27.905] [info][status][plugin:license_management@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:27.907] [info][status][plugin:index_management@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:28.410] [info][status][plugin:timelion@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:28.415] [info][status][plugin:graph@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:28.418] [info][status][plugin:monitoring@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:28.420] [info][status][plugin:security@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:28.420] [warning][security] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [09:51:28.450] [info][status][plugin:grokdebugger@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:28.453] [info][status][plugin:dashboard_mode@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:28.456] [info][status][plugin:logstash@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:28.471] [info][status][plugin:apm@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:28.480] [info][status][plugin:console@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:28.482] [info][status][plugin:console_extensions@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:28.485] [info][status][plugin:metrics@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.471] [warning][reporting] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [09:51:29.473] [info][status][plugin:reporting@6.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [09:51:29.585] [info][listening] Server running at https://x.x.x.x:5601
  log   [09:51:29.589] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.591] [info][license][xpack] Imported license information from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster: mode: basic | status: active
  log   [09:51:29.614] [info][status][plugin:xpack_main@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.615] [info][status][plugin:searchprofiler@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.615] [info][status][plugin:ml@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.615] [info][status][plugin:tilemap@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.616] [info][status][plugin:watcher@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.616] [info][status][plugin:index_management@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.617] [info][status][plugin:graph@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.617] [info][status][plugin:security@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.617] [info][status][plugin:grokdebugger@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.618] [info][status][plugin:logstash@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.618] [info][status][plugin:reporting@6.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [09:51:29.626] [info][kibana-monitoring][monitoring-ui] Starting all Kibana monitoring collectors
  log   [09:51:29.632] [info][license][xpack] Imported license information from Elasticsearch for the [monitoring] cluster: mode: basic | status: active
```

Comment: Have you checked if there is a process that already uses port 5601?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that another task is running on Port 5601. Check the running program on this specific port, kill it, and run the Kibana again.

Comment: After killing another program .. it is working fine as expected